# Rspec with thread

Tags: ruby, multithreading, rspec

I have a class that start a Thread when initialize and I can push some actions in this thread from public methods :

```
class Engine

  def initialize
    @actions = []
    self.start_thread()
  end

  def push_action(action)
    start = @actions.empty?
    @actions.push(action)
    if start
      @thread.run
    end
  end

  protected

  def start_thread
    @thread = Thread.new do
      loop do

        if @actions.empty?
          Thread.stop
        end

        @actions.each do |act|
          # [...]
        end
        @actions.clear
        sleep 1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'd like to test this class with RSpec to check what happen when I pass some actions. But I don't know how to do that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/how-to-test-rails-models-with-rspec

Comment: Thanks @Mark but I don't use rails.

Comment: it's not rspec but a really good write up by Mike Perham is the way to go -> http://www.mikeperham.com/2015/12/14/how-to-test-multithreaded-code/

Comment: Thanks for the link it's a very interesting reading. But something bothering me : "I make its internal API public so that the test suite has full access to the methods". I understand that makes the tests easier to write but is it a good idea ?

Answer (score 0):

OK I've found a solution but it's quite dirty :

```
describe Engine do

  describe "#push_action play" do

    it "should do the play action" do
      # Construct the Engine with a mock thread
      mock_thread = double("Useless Thread")
      allow(mock_thread).to receive(:run)
      expect(Thread).to receive(:new).and_return(mock_thread)
      engine = Engine.new

      allow(engine).to receive(:sleep)

      # Expect that the actual play action will be processed
      expect(engine).to receive(:play)

      # push the action in the actions' list
      engine.push_action(:play)

      # Stop the thread loop when the stop() method is called
      expect(Thread).to receive(:stop).and_raise(StandardError)


      # Manually call again the start_thread() protected method with a yielded thread
      # in order to process the action
      expect(Thread).to receive(:new).and_yield
      expect {engine.send(:start_thread)}.to raise_error(StandardError)  
    end

  end
end
```

If someone has a better solution I'd be very pleased :)

Comment: i think it's a good idea to split this up into multiple tests. Test each method in isolation.

Comment: What do you mean ? The only method I want to test here is `push_action`. The "real" behaviour of my method is handle by the `start_thread` but it shouldn't impact my unit test, should it ?